# iOS ViewController After Load Method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm trying to find a method thats called once everything has been loaded and displayed. The reason I want to do this is because I have some images that take some time to load in so instead of showing them a black screen I want to show a loading page and then call a setup method.
However the only methods I can find are called before the views come into view...
I am probably being really dumb..
Any help would be great.
Disco

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
- (void)viewWillLoad;
```

and

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;
```

to do what you need.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;
```